# how to keep scroll position on any click in the same page in angular 8

Tags: angular, angular8

how to keep scroll position on any click in the same page in angular 8?

if there are 4 tabs in the same page and after I click on different tabs in same page then I do not want to reset scroll position. I want want keep scroll position.

Comment: in app-routing.module.ts try:  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { scrollPositionRestoration: 'disabled' })],

Comment: tried but not working... any other solution?